# How to know the Id of the facebook like button

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am creating a website that users are supposed to download a video after they like the video using the Facebook like button.That is if someone likes the post on Facebook, instead of them showing the inactive "you like this" button, it shows a download link with the video URL. I have implemented the like button but for the download button  not yet. Anyone with an Idea of how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap like button in `div` element with given `id`, then you will be able always get like button.

Comment: I want to kwo the Id of the facebook like button.

Comment: ... but what kind of element is fb like button? div? button? it doesn't matter if you only want to assign its onClick event. if You use jQuery you could always do something like that: `$("div#wrapper button").click(function(){ // your action after like your page })`.